# What are the terms for individual elements in a binary relation?

Tags: terminology, relations

Let's suggest we have a binary relation $R$ such that:
$$aRb$$

I am wondering what is the proper term for the individual elements $a$ and $b$ in the context of relation $R$.

Coming from the IT world, I would perhaps refer to $a$ as the *key* and $b$ as the *value*. But this does not feel like the proper terminology in mathematics and, to my surprise, I was unable to find the answer at my usual go-to places for such matter.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: The problem with key and value is there is no real reason to distinguish one side from the other, so which is the key and which is the value would be arbitrary.

Comment: In the IT world, I would call them left operand and right operand, respectively.

Comment: In the math world, you could call them $x$-coordinate, $y$-coordinate.

Comment: In analogy to the relations $=$ and $\le$, I might call them the "left-hand side" and the "right-hand side" if I really needed to refer to them and they didn't already have names somehow (e.g. if $R$ were the subset relation, then they could be the "subset" and the "superset" in a certain context).

Comment: According to Wikipedia's [Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) section of their "Binary relation" page, the $a$ are elements of the "*set of departure*" and the $b$ are elements of the "*set of destination* or *codomain*". I realize this is rather wordy, but I believe it's an accurate way to describe them.

Comment: @MattSamuel Agreed, moreover these terms only make sense in case of functional relations.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Good point.